# ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError on hover over any element in Angular

Tags: angular, angular6

I'm using `Angular 6`.

In one of the component HTML file, I want to display a list of items with random background color.

```
<span class="bg-{{ getRandomColor() }}">
     <i class="ion ion-ios-filing"></i>
</span>
```

and defined `getRandomColor()` function inside the component file

```
export class DashboardComponent {

  constructor(
    private colorService: ColorService
  ) {
  }

  getRandomColor() {
    return this.colorService.getRandomColorClass();
  }
}
```

and **ColorClassService** is like

```
export class ColorService {

  private _colors = [
    'primary',
    'secondary',
    'warning',
    'success',
    'info',
    'danger'
  ];

  constructor() { }

  getRandomColor() {
    return this._colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * this._colors.length)];
  }
}
```

This works fine as the random color is being retrieved.

**But when the mouse is moved over any element on the page, the color is changing and error in console is like**

```
ERROR Error: "ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. 
Previous value: 'className: bg-primary'. Current value: 'className: bg-danger'."
```

Comment: Your problem is called change detection. There's a lot of good resources about change detection and this specific error, my very basic recommendation is to read them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a change detection issue, as pointed out by @Ingo in the comments of your question.

To explain further, Angular runs a change detection cycle when you hover over the elements.

Because it runs a cycle, it renders a new CSS class on said elements, since you use a randomizer.

To avoid that, use the `onPush` change detection strategy; or stop using functions in your HTML templates unless you listen to events (which you don't in this case).